# Creating a Custom Entity Framework for Unsupported System

Tags: entity-framework, ibm-midrange

I could be totally misunderstanding Entity Framework here. I want to use that in my latest project (how else do you learn?) The problem is that the IBM i driver doesn't have support for that built in. Is is possible to create that framework from scratch? It is worth it?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing, but I was discouraged by the answer to [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546120/).  What's involved in writing one's own "data provider"?  (I don't know enough about EF [or ADO.NET for that matter] to answer that question.)

Comment: @dmc Ya, I  found that post too. I wish IBM would include it in the i Access ADO.NET drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be writing your own ADO.NET data provider to connect to IBM DB2 for i.  Microsoft provides [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789835.aspx) for creating your own provider and a [sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider).

The data provider would be responsible for communicating with the database, so I'm not sure how you'd accomplish that.  Either you'd be implementing your own connection to the database server running on the i (maybe you can port the SQL piece of [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/)), or you'd be delegating your calls to the IBM-provided data provider (if that's even possible) or other data access method.

I couldn't decide whether I thought this was (1) a huge pain in the butt or (2) an opportunity for an open source project.  (I guess it could be both.)  It seems like it'd be easier to lobby IBM to make this part of their stock provider.  You might complain about it on [MIDRANGE-L](http://www.midrange.com/) and see if people will take up the cause.

Disclaimer:  I am a newbie in the .NET world, so maybe there's an easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was actually starting to think about #2. IBM is WAY behind on the .NET drivers. However, I don't have the time do lead such a beast. The first two links is actually what I have been trying to find for quite a while now. Thanks! The problem was getting the right terminology to do the right search. If only Google can guess at what you are _actually_ searching for.

Comment: Yeah, I spent a few minutes wondering if this might be a fun (!) and educational project for getting my feet wet with .NET.  However, after a bit more discovery it began looking more like deep sea diving without a breathing device.