# Connect to DB2 using EF6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, db2

I have a WPF app using EF6 and I need to connect to a DB2 database.

I have my data layer in a separate library from the main app.  My connection string in the App.config looks like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TIMSContext" connectionString="Database=DB2C;UID=blah;PWD=blahblah;Server=myServer:446;" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have a reference to the IBM DB2 EntityFramework package in my data library.

When I try to run, I get an error saying that the provider cannot be found.

If I try to include a reference to the IBM EF package in the main app, I get a type initializer error at startup.

Comment: Do you have DB2 Connect installed?

Comment: No...  I have the DB2 client and drivers.  I can connect to the server via WinSQL and others.  Just not in the application.

Comment: What is the type initializer error? No more info about it also in InnerException?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible. You need a license for `DB2 Connect` aside from your company's iSeries license (someone please correct me if I'm wrong; I would be very happy to hear of an alternative).

As such, we are forced to continue using MyGeneration dOOdads at my company, which has not been supported for almost a decade. -.-

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546120/is-it-possible-to-use-entity-framework-with-a-db2-iseries-as-400) for more; I don't think anything has changed since then...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently DB2 has issues with EF6... I backed down to EF5 and it all worked fine.